# Magento2: New Product collection

Tags: magento2

How to load new product collection in magento 2 like we did in magento 1.x something like

```
->addAttributeToFilter('news_from_date', array('date' => true, 'to' => $todayDate))
```

Comment: You can check this answer its working well you can [Check here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/273805/how-to-get-latest-products-collection-in-my-costum-module-magento-2)

Answer (score 11):

You can try this :

```
public function __construct(
\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Attribute\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
    array $data = []
    ) {

    $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

public function getProductCollection()
{       
    $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
    $todayDate  = date('Y-m-d', time());
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('news_from_date', array('date' => true, 'to' => $todayDate));

    return $collection;
}
```

Comment: You can always accept the answer if it helped so as it serves a point of reference for others too.!

Answer (score 8):

As you want ***to get a product collection*** then you need to   get first `current data start & end time`.

**So you can try below**

> ```
> $todayStartOfDayDate = $this->_localeDate->date()->setTime(0, 0, 0)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
> $todayEndOfDayDate = $this->_localeDate->date()->setTime(23, 59, 59)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
> ```

Then using *`news_from_date`*  and *`news_to_date`* fields ,you need to ***filter collection  current data start and end time*** with date format  (Y-m-d H:i:s);

**Collection filter should be like this:**

```
   $collection->addStoreFilter()->addAttributeToFilter(
            'news_from_date',
            [
                'or' => [
                    0 => ['date' => true, 'to' => $todayEndOfDayDate],
                    1 => ['is' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('null')],
                ]
            ],
            'left'
        )->addAttributeToFilter(
            'news_to_date',
            [
                'or' => [
                    0 => ['date' => true, 'from' => $todayStartOfDayDate],
                    1 => ['is' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('null')],
                ]
            ],
            'left'
        )->addAttributeToFilter(
            [
                ['attribute' => 'news_from_date', 'is' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('not null')],
                ['attribute' => 'news_to_date', 'is' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('not null')],
            ]
        )
```

See More at class  [Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\New](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Block/Product/NewProduct.php#L124) Block at Magento2.

**You Can use this block for ur purpose**