# How to get Latest Products Collection in my costum Module Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, product-collection

I want to get Collection of Latest Products in Magento 2
i have some restriction

- Without using Object Manager
- Without using API

i have searched on internet found these two methods but i have to avoid using them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a **Block class** and inject **`Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory`** in the constructor and you can get/display product collection in **`phtml`** file.

Check below code:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

class ProductDisplay extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{    
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,        
        array $data = []
    )
    {    
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;    
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getProductCollection()
    {
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $collection->setPageSize(5); // fetching only 3 products
        $colletion->setOrder('created_at','DESC'); //sort by date created 
        return $collection;
    }
}
```

In your **`phtml`** file:

```
$productCollection = $block->getProductCollection();
foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
    print_r($product->getData());     
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: please explain how you have used logic for latest products.. i am not getting that

Comment: updated the answer with sort order